# How to zoom into a specific location of an image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code to zoom into an image:

```
<style type="text/css">
.thumbnail {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(3); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(3); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(3); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(3); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(3);
}
 </style>


 <div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="image">
   <img src="example.jpg" alt="Image zoom">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Currently this code works except for in will only zoom to the center of the image.
My question is: How can I zoom into a pre-determined location (could be as simple as just left or right as opposed to the center that it currently is.) I would like to achieve the outcome using CSS if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the **[Transform Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)** property and you can set the origin point. This will allow you to control where the zoom occurs from/to.

`transform-origin: top right;` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help.